# Does the Frétchet derivative exist of this minimizer map?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Banach space $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm. On this space, define a map $\inf:C[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f \mapsto \inf_{x \in [0,1]}{f(x)} $. By compactness of $[0,1]$, this map is well defined.

I was able to prove that this map is continous. But I am not able to tell whether or not this function admits a Frétchet derivative at a general point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $F:X\to Y$ is Frechet differentiable. For $x,y\in X$ define $F_{x,y}:\Bbb R\to Y$ by $$F_{x,y}(t)=F(x+ty).$$Show that $F_{x,y}$ is differentiable...

Comment: This is a nice result. Where can I get to read more about the theory of Fretchet derivatives in detail?

Comment: @nihargargava I wouldn't know, sorry.